# Why does java.util.Properties implement Map<Object,Object> and not Map<String,String>

Tags: java, generics, collections

The `java.util.Properties` class is meant to represent a map where the keys and values are both Strings. This is because `Properties` objects are used to read `.properties` files, which are text files.

So, why in Java 5 did they retrofit this class to implement `Map<Object,Object>` and not `Map<String,String>`?

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) states:

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead. If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail.

Since the keys and values are both supposed to be Strings then why not enforce that statically by using the proper generic type?

I guess making `Properties` implement `Map<String,String>` would not be fully backward compatible with code written for pre-Java 5. If you have older code that sticks non-strings into a Properties object then that code would no longer compile with Java 5. But... isn't that a good thing? Isn't the whole point of generics to catch such type errors at compile time?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because they did it in a hurry in the early days of Java, and didn't realise what the implications would be four versions later.

Generics were supposed to be part of the design of Java from the beginning, but the feature was dropped as being too complicated and, at the time, unnecessary. As a result, lots of code in the standard libraries is written with the assumption of non-generic collections. It took the prototype language "Pizza" from Martin Odersky to show how they could be done fairly well while maintaining near perfect backwards compatibility, with both Java code and bytecode. The prototype led to Java 5, in which the collections classes were retrofitted with generics in a way that allowed old code to keep working.

Unfortunately, if they were to retroactively make `Properties` inherit from `Map<String, String>`, then the following previously valid code would stop working:

```
Map<Object, Object> x = new Properties()
x.put("flag", true)
```

Why anybody would do that is beyond me, but Sun's commitment to backwards compatibility in Java has gone beyond heroic into the pointless.

What's now appreciated by most educated observers is that `Properties` should never have inherited from `Map` at all. It should instead wrap around `Map`, exposing only those features of Map that make sense.

Since reinventing Java, Martin Odersky has gone on to create the new Scala language, which is cleaner, inherits fewer mistakes, and breaks new ground in a number of areas. If you're finding Java's niggles annoying, take a look at it.

Comment: Actually Map x = new Properties() work either way.  Its people putting things like properties.put("flag", Boolean.TRUE); I have seen people put all kinds of data into a Properties object, but never a non-String key. ;)

Comment: Wait a minute! Map<Object,Object> x = new Properties() is not legal pre-Java 5, the <Object,Object> syntax was introduced in Java 5. So the statement "previously valid code" is incorrect.

Comment: Read my sentence again. What I said is that they aren't able to fix it, because doing so would break people's code.

Answer (score 27):

It was originally intended that `Properties` would indeed extends `Hashtable<String,String>`. Unfortunately the implementation of bridge methods caused a problem. `Properties` defined in such a way causes javac to generate synthetic methods. `Properties` should define, say, a `get` method that returns a `String` but needs to override a method that returns `Object`. So a synthetic bridge method is added.

Suppose you had a class written in the bad old 1.4 days. You've overridden some methods in `Properties`. But what you haven't done is overridden the new methods. This leads to unintended behaviour. To avoid these bridge methods, `Properties` extends `Hashtable<Object,Object>`. Similarly `Iterable` does not return a (read-only) `SimpleIterable`, because that would have added methods to `Collection` implementations.

Answer (score 13):

A one-liner (two-liner for no warnings) for creating Map from Properties:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
Map<String, String> sysProps = new HashMap(System.getProperties());
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. But does answer what caused the question in the first place. Straight to the point.

Comment: Is "rawtypes" necessary here? (At least in my IntelliJ IDEA, "unchecked" is sufficient for supressing any warnings.)

Answer (score 3):

Backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The reason: [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and backwards compatibility. `Properties` extends `Hashtable` and thus must accept all messages that `Hashtable` would accept - and that means accepting `put(Object, Object)`. And it has to extend plain `Hashtable` instead of `Hashtable<String, String>` because Generics were implemented in the downwards-compatibe way via [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so once the compiler has done its thing, there are no generics.

Comment: I don't think the Liskov substitution principle has anything to do with it. Java happily lets you refine generic types when you inherit a class. That's why the <T extends Sometype> and <T super Sometype> syntax exists.