# Why java Dictionary interface become obsolete and was replaced by Map?

Tags: java

The Dictionary class is now obsolete,   replaced    by  java.util.Map interface –   why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358651/are-java-properties-effectively-deprecated

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this question asks "why" while the "dup" in the link asks for differences and none of the 3 answers actually answer this one. Please re-open.

Comment: `Hashtable` and `Properties` still both extend it. Note that none of these classes is deprecated. The motivation for the Java Collections Framework is described completely in the [Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Comment: Dictionary was replaced with Map, which has a much richer set of functions.  Updating Dictionary to add the functionality would have likely broken a lot of exiting code.  This was done at the same time that Hashtable was replaced by HashMap.  One important difference between these is that Hashtable was internally synchronized while HashMap is not.  As it turned out the synchronization was quite expensive and it was far from "airtight" anyway.