# Converting java.util.Properties to HashMap<String,String>

Tags: java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(properties);// why wrong?
```

[`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a implementation of [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), And [`java.util.HashMap`'s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-) receives a `Map` type param. So, why must it be converted explicitly?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is because [`Properties` extends `Hashtable<Object, Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) (which, in turn, implements `Map<Object, Object>`). You attempt to feed that into a `Map<String, String>`. It is therefore incompatible.

You need to feed string properties one by one into your map...

For instance:

```
for (final String name: properties.stringPropertyNames())
    map.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem here: the generic arguments don't match. You can feed whatever you want in a `Hashtable<Object, Object>`, even things which are not strings -- even _keys_ which are not strings.

Comment: @assylias: No, that won't compile either.

Comment: in 1,8 you can do
      properties.forEach( (k,v) -> map.put((String)k, (String)v));

Comment: Or if you don't have already the map in hand
    properties.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e->(String)e.getKey(),e->(String)e.getValue()))

Answer (score 55):

The efficient way to do that is just to cast to a generic Map as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

Map<String, String> map = (Map)props;
```

This will convert a `Map<Object, Object>` to a raw Map, which is "ok" for the compiler (only warning). Once we have a raw `Map` it will cast to `Map<String, String>` which it also will be "ok" (another warning). You can ignore them with annotation `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })`

This will work because in the JVM the object doesn't really have a generic type. Generic types are just a trick that verifies things at compile time.

If some key or value is not a String it will produce a `ClassCastException` error. With current `Properties` implementation this is very unlikely to happen, as long as you don't use the mutable call methods from the super `Hashtable<Object,Object>` of `Properties`.

So, if don't do nasty things with your Properties instance this is the way to go.

Comment: The question is to convert to HashMap. Not any Map.

Comment: Yes, the question title says that, but the goal is to have a `Map` instance at least at the given code, so I thought that this is what he needs

Comment: Although I like other purists solutions, this solution comes handy to me since it is only one simple line.

Answer (score 39):

You could use Google Guava's:

[com.google.common.collect.Maps.fromProperties(Properties)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#fromProperties(java.util.Properties))

Answer (score 30):

The Java 8 way:

```
properties.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
         e -> e.getKey().toString(),
         e -> e.getValue().toString()
    )
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use method reference instead of lambda. Cos of sonar qube issues.

Answer (score 28):

How about this?

```
   Map properties = new Properties();
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(properties);
```

Will cause a warning, but works without iterations.

Comment: @fge: It's not a `Map<Object, Object>`, it's a `Map` argument (raw type). This answer is correct

Comment: Huh, yes I tried with Eclipse. One of those generic differences between Eclipse and javac again? .... nope, works with javac as well

Comment: This works but the iteration still happens. If you look at the source code for HashMap, the constructor basically iterates through the generic map parameter. So the computation time does not change but the code is certainly more concise.

Comment: As the previous answer stated, there's no need to create a new instance and iterate over the properties object. Just use a sequence of casts:  
`(Map<String, String>) ((Map) properties)`

Answer (score 18):

`Properties` implements `Map<Object, Object>` - not `Map<String, String>`.

You're trying to call this constructor:

```
public HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)
```

... with `K` and `V` both as `String`.

But `Map<Object, Object>` isn't a `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`... it can contain non-string keys and values.

This would work:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

... but it wouldn't be as useful to you.

Fundamentally, `Properties` should never have been made a subclass of `HashTable`... that's the problem. Since v1, it's always been able to store non-String keys and values, despite that being against the intention. If composition had been used instead, the API could have *only* worked with string keys/values, and all would have been well.

You may want something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    map.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
}
```

Comment: apparently it is also not possible to explicitly do `Properties<String,String> properties = new Properties<String,String>();`. Peculiar.

Comment: @eis That's by design, `Properties` itself is not generic.

Comment: I'd rather say it's by unfortunate series of choices rather than by design, but yeah.

Comment: @eis: No, it's by design that Properties is meant to be a string-to-string map. It makes sense that it's not generic. It *doesn't* make sense that you can add non-string keys/values.

Answer (score 10):

I would use following Guava API:
[com.google.common.collect.Maps#fromProperties](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#fromProperties(java.util.Properties))

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Map<String, String> map = Maps.fromProperties(properties);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you *know* that your `Properties` object only contains `<String, String>` entries, you can resort to a raw type:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>((Map) properties);
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `Properties` implements `Map<Object, Object>`, whereas the `HashMap` constructor expects a `Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/873691/1321716) explains this (quite counter-intuitive) decision. In short: before Java 5, `Properties` implemented `Map` (as there were no generics back then). This meant that you could put *any* `Object` in a `Properties` object. [This is still in the documenation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

> Because `Properties` inherits from `Hashtable`, the `put` and `putAll` methods
>   can be applied to a `Properties` object. Their use is strongly
>   discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or
>   values are not `String`s. The `setProperty` method should be used instead.

To maintain compatibility with this, the designers had no other choice but to make it inherit `Map<Object, Object>` in Java 5. It's an unfortunate result of the strive for full backwards compatibility which makes new code unnecessarily convoluted.

If you only ever use string properties in your `Properties` object, you *should* be able to get away with an unchecked cast in your constructor:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>( (Map<String, String>) properties);
```

or without any copies:

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) properties;
```

Comment: This is the signature of HashMap constructor `public HashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)`. It doesn't expects a `Map<String, String>`

Comment: @Mubin Okay, I oversimplified the matter a bit. Still, the argument holds: a `Map<Object, Object>` cannot be used for a formal argument of type` Map<? extends String, ? extends String>`.

Answer (score 2):

this is only because the constructor of HashMap requires an arg of Map generic type and Properties implements Map.

This will work, though with a warning

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

props.forEach((key, value) -> map.put(key.toString(), value.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing,

> Properties class is based on Hashtable and not Hashmap. Properties class basically extends Hashtable

There is no such constructor in HashMap class which takes a properties object and return you a hashmap object. So what you are doing is NOT correct. You should be able to cast the object of properties to hashtable reference.

Answer (score 0):

i use this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry:properties.entrySet()) {
    map.put((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I see Spring framework source code,I find this way

```java
Properties props = getPropertiesFromSomeWhere();
 // change properties to map
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap(props)
```