# How to convert all Java System Properties to HashMap<String,String>?

Tags: java, hashmap, system-properties

This [nice article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-list-all-system-properties-key-and-value-in-java/) shows us how to print all the current system properties to STDOUT, but I need to convert everything that's in `System.getProperties()` to a `HashMap<String,String>`.

Hence if there is a system property called "baconator", with a value of "yes!", that I set with `System.setProperty("baconator, "yes!")`, then I want the `HashMap` to have a key of `baconator` and a respective value of `yes!`, etc. Same idea for **all** system properties.

I tried this:

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
for(String propertyName : systemProperties.keySet())
    ;
```

But then get an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

So then I tried:

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
for(String propertyName : (String)systemProperties.keySet())
    ;
```

And am getting this error:

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209260/converting-java-util-properties-to-hashmapstring-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a sample test using `Map.Entry`

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
for(Entry<Object, Object> x : systemProperties.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(x.getKey() + " " + x.getValue());
}
```

For your case, you can use this to store it in your `Map<String, String>`:

```
Map<String, String> mapProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
for(Entry<Object, Object> x : systemProperties.entrySet()) {
    mapProperties.put((String)x.getKey(), (String)x.getValue());
}

for(Entry<String, String> x : mapProperties.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(x.getKey() + " " + x.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, you can type this -rather long- one-liner:

```
Map<String, String> map = System.getProperties().entrySet().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> (String) e.getKey(), e -> (String) e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the `Set<String>` (which is `Iterable`) that is returned by the [`stringPropertyNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) method.  When processing each property name, use [`getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) to get the property value.  Then you have the information needed to `put` your property values into your `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

This does work

```
Properties properties= System.getProperties();
for (Object key : properties.keySet()) {
    Object value= properties.get(key);

    String stringKey= (String)key;
    String stringValue= (String)value;

    //just put it in a map: map.put(stringKey, stringValue);
    System.out.println(stringKey + " " + stringValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the `entrySet()` method from `Properties` to get an `Entry` type from `Properties` which is `Iterable` or you could use the `stringPropertyNames()` method from the `Properties` class to get a `Set` of keys in this property list. The use the `getProperty` method to get the property value.