# Using .properties file in Spring Info contributor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am writing a custom Info Contributor. I have a properties file that is generated during the build process in target/classes folder.
How Can I use this generated file in the custom info contributor.

I checked the below code for [GitInfoContributor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/info/GitInfoContributor.java)

```
public class GitInfoContributor extends InfoPropertiesInfoContributor<GitProperties> {

    public GitInfoContributor(GitProperties properties) {
        this(properties, Mode.SIMPLE);
    }

    public GitInfoContributor(GitProperties properties, Mode mode) {
        super(properties, mode);
    }

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        builder.withDetail("git", generateContent());
    }

    @Override
    protected PropertySource<?> toSimplePropertySource() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        copyIfSet(props, "branch");
        String commitId = getProperties().getShortCommitId();
        if (commitId != null) {
            props.put("commit.id", commitId);
        }
        copyIfSet(props, "commit.time");
        return new PropertiesPropertySource("git", props);
    }

    /**
     * Post-process the content to expose. By default, well known keys representing dates
     * are converted to {@link Instant} instances.
     * @param content the content to expose
     */
    @Override
    protected void postProcessContent(Map<String, Object> content) {
        replaceValue(getNestedMap(content, "commit"), "time", getProperties().getCommitTime());
        replaceValue(getNestedMap(content, "build"), "time", getProperties().getInstant("build.time"));
    }

}
```

I am not able to figure out how the git properties are being injected to GitProperties class here ?
I need to do the same for my custom info contributor using my properties file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a git contributor, Spring boot also comes with a [`EnvironmentInfoContributor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d370d19e7a26623f0076765e257230f28e152ade/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/info/EnvironmentInfoContributor.java). This contributor automatically includes all application properties starting with `info.*`.

So the easiest solution is to make sure your custom properties all start with `info.*` and to treat your custom properties file as an additional application properties file. This can be done by providing the `spring.config.additional-location` VM argument. For example:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:custom-properties myApp.jar
```

Now you only have to enable the environment info contributor by setting:

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
```

If this isn't possible, you can indeed write your own contributor. One way of doing so is by [programmatically reading your properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1771166/1915448) and [converting it to a `Map<String, String>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209260/converting-java-util-properties-to-hashmapstring-string). Once that's done, you can call the `Info.Builder.withDetails(..)` method with your `Map` (see the source code of `EnvironmentInfoContributor`).

Comment: I am aware of this. What I am trying to achieve is to show all the other dependencies on which this project depends on , in the /actuator/info endpoint.  Also I need to modify the values present in the custom properties file a bit before they can be directly used.

Comment: @Sam In that case you may want to check the last paragraph I added. You could read your properties-file programmatically, do your modifications, put it in a `Map<String, String>` and call the `Info.Builder.withDetails()` method.