# Most pythonic way to append Dictionary with specific keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

A dictionary like `Dict = {'Key_1': 'Data_1', 'Key_2': 'Data_2', ..., 'Key_n': 'Data_n'}` contains `n` keys named in ascending order.

A method like `AddNextKey(Dict, NewData)` should determine the last key `n` and add a new one `n+1` with value `NewData`.
If `Dict` is empty, the method should append key `Key_1`.

I am quite sure that a pythonic solution does not require more than two or three lines of code to achieve this.

Remark: It is not important that the dictionary is ordered. Only the correct next key (n+1) must be appended.

Could anybody give advice?

Comment: If your keys ascend numerically, then why not use a list, and append to the end of the list?

Comment: What's your current solution, and what's unpythonic about it?

Comment: What? As per my understanding `dict`s are un-ordered. How are they ascending? Please can you explain a bit? Do you mean keys are in continuation?

Comment: If you're looking at having a sorted dictionary, I would use orderedDict from the [collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

Comment: Wow. So many comments in such a short time :) @turbulencetoo: Unfortunately, I need to have a dictionary due to some other external constraints.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, it is using way to many loops...

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri: Yes. Key_1, Key_2, Key_3, Key_4, ..., Key_10, ..., Key_100, ..., Key_n

Comment: Please add it to the question. If you have **working code** that you think could be improved, it may be a better fit for [codereview.se].

Comment: you can always keep `n` as element in dictionary - ie. `Dict['last_n'] = 100` and use in your function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't have access to my lab PC right now but it looks pretty much like the one posted by Michael Ellner

Comment: I wonder if it even could be considered pythonic to do this? It's complicated to get it right, and what's the benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no order in a dictionary. And you can not get the last inserted element from it.

Take a look at this example:

```
>>> {'Key_1': 'Data_1', 'Key_2': 'Data_2'} == {'Key_2': 'Data_2', 'Key_1': 'Data_1'}
True
```

As you can see, the order is meaningless for the `dict`.

The question is what exactly do you mean by the last key n. Last inserted? Or with biggest key_%index%? In first case you better to use OrderedDict, as already mentioned.

However, here is my solution, if I got you right.

```
def AddNextKey(Dict, NewData):
    Dict['Key_%d' % (len(Dict) + 1)] = NewData

d = {}
AddNextKey(d, 'Data_1')
AddNextKey(d, 'Data_2')
AddNextKey(d, 'Data_3')

print d
```

You will get

```
{'Key_1': 'Data_1', 'Key_3': 'Data_3', 'Key_2': 'Data_2'}
```

Comment: Yes, sth. like this I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the most Pythonic solution but my approach is to subclass `dict` and add that additional method. Since it's a subclass, you can use an instance of `NextKeyDict` anywhere you could an actual `dict`, but also perform these special operations where needed.

```
class NextKeyDict(dict):
    def add_next_key(self, new_data):
        if not self.keys():
            self[0] = new_data
            return

        last_key = sorted(self.keys())[-1]
        new_key = last_key + 1
        self[new_key] = new_data

d = NextKeyDict()
d.add_next_key('foo')
d.add_next_key('bar')
d.add_next_key('baz')
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz'}
```

Comment: @RolandSmith Right. Python is a language of "consenting adults", right? My thinking would be to ensure this class/method has appropriate documentation that explains it's only suitable for use with integer keys and leave the burden of ensuring that on the user. What modifications would you make?

Comment: I would override some methods to ensure that you cannot insert an improper key. Not to be pedantic, but to make the solution robust. To catch mistakes before they turn into bugs. The more special rules ("all keys in dict X should have the format 'Key_N'") code has, the more the programmers need to keep in their mind.

Comment: @RolandSmith I think that would break the Liskov Substitution Principle. Right now my dict can be used "as is" by any class that expects a `dict`, and the only potential pitfall would be to call `add_next_key` when the keys aren't integers - but classes expecting `dict` would not be aware of this method anyway. You make a valid point though - an alternative would be to use *composition* instead of subclassing, to make a class that internally uses a dict but throws exceptions if trying to store non-integers as keys.

Comment: Remember the mistake that was [Java's Properties class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873510/why-does-java-util-properties-implement-mapobject-object-and-not-mapstring-st) haha? Yeah, a composition approach may have been better here.

Comment: Luckily, I've never been unfortunate enough to have to use Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the length of the dictionary

```
Dict = dict()
for i in range(10):
    Dict['key_' + str(len(Dict)+1)] = 'value_'+str(len(Dict)+1)
print Dict
```

Outputs

```
{'key_10': 'value_10', 'key_5': 'value_5', 'key_4': 'value_4', 'key_7': 'value_7', 'key_6': 'value_6', 'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_3': 'value_3', 'key_2': 'value_2', 'key_9': 'value_9', 'key_8': 'value_8'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal Python dictionaries are unordered. So technically, there is no "last" key.

But there is a way around that. You could use the `len` method to see how many items there are in the dictionary, and construct the next key based on that.

But note that this method is *fragile*. if you accidentally add a key 'foo' to the dictionary, your whole scheme is off.

To *really* fix this you would have to create a subclass of `dict` (by overriding the `__setitem__` and `update` methods as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588648/1219295)) so that it only accepts valid keys in the form `'Key_N'`. You could then also add an `append` method to automatically create the next key.

But as turbulencetoo commented, it would probably be easier to use a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set-up the dictionary for demo purposes
testdict = {x:y for x,y in zip(["Key_"+str(x) for x in range(1,7)],
                               ["Data_"+str(x) for x in range(1,7)])}

# fetch most recent key
# add 1 to recent_key_val and insert new value
if len(testdict) != 0:
    recent_key_val = max([int(x.split("_")[1]) for x in testdict])
    testdict["Key_"+str(recent_key_val +1)] = "New_Data"
else:
    testdict["Key_1"] = "New_Data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you need is already built into Python. So I think the most pythonic way is to use OrderedDict.
As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) say

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
d["Key1"] = 1
d["Key2"] = 2
d["Key3"] = 3

last_key = d.keys()[-1]  # "Key3" thanks to ordering
new_key = calculate_new_key(last_key)
d[new_key] = new_value
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, python dictionary are an unordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique.
Given that you can use OrderedDict from class collections to create and update the dictionary and preserve the order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d1 = OrderedDict([(1, 'Data_1'), (2, 'Data_2'),(3, 'Data_3')])
```

You get

```
OrderedDict([(1, 'Data_1'), (2, 'Data_2'), (3, 'Data_3')])
```

Now the method to update the dictionary

```
def AddNextKey(Dict, NewData):
    last_key = next(reversed(Dict))
    new_key = last_key + 1
    Dict.update({new_key: NewData})
```

When you call

```
AddNextKey(d1, 'Blah')
```

You get

```
OrderedDict([(1, 'Data_1'), (2, 'Data_2'), (3, 'Data_3'), (4, 'Blah')])
```